# Recursive code for searching max height of binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

I've created a tree using this code (this is outdated look at the bottom, problem updated):

```
struct node* buildTree() {
  struct node* root = NULL;
  root = insert(root, 2);
  root = insert(root, 4);
  root = insert(root, 10);
  return(root);
}
```

Then tried to find max depth of that (functions Max and insert work properly), using this:

```
int maxHeight(struct node* p) {
  if(p == NULL) {return 0;}
  else{
    int leftDepth = 1 + maxHeight(p->left);
    int rightDepth = 1 + maxHeight(p->right);
    return(Max(leftDepth, rightDepth));
  }
}
```

And it shows me error like max depth is 3; I've compiled in `C99` standard. I've found this and similar code in several places in the Internet, but here doesn't work, any ideas what's wrong? Thanks..

As suggested adding insert code:

```
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data) {
  if (node == NULL) {
    return(newNode(data));
  }
  else {
    if (data <= node->data) node->left = insert(node->left, data);
    else node->right = insert(node->right, data);
    return(node); 
  }
}
```

And newNode function:

```
struct node* newNode(int data) {
  struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  return(node);
}
```

Update: 
 New buildTree function:

```
struct node* buildTree() {
  struct node* root = newNode(3);
  root->left = newNode(2);
  root->right = newNode(1);

  return(root);
}
```

Comment: mb your insert works wrong?

Comment: It depends on your function insert. If Considered  it to be a binary tree, then the depth is correct

Comment: function of calculating maxHeight is correct. Might be their is problem in insertion...

Answer (score 0):

The code works but it looks like the tree you built is not what you meant, probably as you keep concatenating a new node to the previous node (and not to the single root).
Assuming the insert returns the node just created then your first add a tree node 2: 
Tree: `(2)`
The you're adding a tree node 4 as a child of tree node 2:
Tree: `(2)--(4)`
Finally you're adding a tree node 10 as a child of tree node 4:
Tree: `(2)--(4)--(10)`

So as you can see the tree depth is 3 (including the root).

Comment: I see what you're saying now I guess, but it seems like you're making assumptions about the insert. It seems like you're saying the tree is inserting in a list fashion.

Comment: My only assumption is that insert(x, y) creates a node for value y and places it as a child of x. No assumption is made about whether it is a list or another data structure

Comment: Likely this is true, I'm working on to create tree in different way.

Comment: @AmnonShochot. Thanks you were right, I've changed building tree method(and 've updated post). Now it gives me height 2, as you said, including root, but according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Depth-first_order , height of that tree should be 1 not 2.

Comment: It is probably a tree Height vs. tree Depth. As your code returns the tree Height in order to return the tree depth all you have to do is return `Height-1`.

Comment: @AmnonShochot, Yes that's true,due to yr answer the question is solved.